# How to redirect to Backbone router inside some other function

Tags: javascript, redirect, backbone.js

quick question. I have router which redirects to different parts of the application. One of them is for example game, one is menu etc.

I now want a simple function in javascript that redirects to #game or #menu for example. I know I could use Model with .set function but would that still work the same way?

This is the file where I want to call this redirection:

```
var Controls = BaseView.extend({
    id: "controls",
    template: require('./controls.tpl'),
    events: {
      'click #game': 'gotoGame',
      'click #menu': 'gotoMenu'
    },

    gotoGame: function() {
        //Redirect to #game
    }
});
```

And router is inside other file game_router like this:

```
var Router = BackboneRouteControl.extend({
    routes: {
        'menu': 'menu#index',
        'game': 'game#show'
    }
})
```

So how can I redirect just to "someaddress"/#game inside one function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Router.navigate`. In your case it should be something like this:

```
routerInstance.navigate("game", {trigger: true});
```

http://backbonejs.org/#Router-navigate

Comment: Thanks, it should work like this but I get error cannot read property of undefined for `login`  in this line `controller = this.controllers[controllerName];` (from Backbonerouter.js files). Login is also one of my routes, actually the first one `'login': 'login#create'`

Comment: It comes from `require('backbone-route-control');` so it I can see it only in source code where I get from error in console. I can paste whole code of this function?

Comment: I suggest you to post a jsfiddle which shows the error. I'm pretty sure what I've posted works with Backbone. I see that you're using an extension above `Backbone.Router`, maybe the problem is there.

Comment: It works now, had to make couple of changes in order to get the right router. Meanwhile I could use `window.location.href = 'somelink' ` and got the same result as router catches that path.